# Unresolved dependency trying to access Apache Sedona context with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, geopandas, apache-sedona

I am trying to use Apache Sedona with Python, specifically with PySpark version 3.5.0 and Python 3.11.6. However, I am encountering an issue related to an unresolved dependency during the setup process. The relevant part of the error message is as follows:

```
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: edu.ucar#cdm-core;5.4.2

==== local-m2-cache: tried

  file:/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/cdm-core-5.4.2.pom

  -- artifact edu.ucar#cdm-core;5.4.2!cdm-core.jar:

  file:/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/cdm-core-5.4.2.jar

==== local-ivy-cache: tried

  /.ivy2/local/edu.ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/ivys/ivy.xml

  -- artifact edu.ucar#cdm-core;5.4.2!cdm-core.jar:

  /.ivy2/local/edu.ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/jars/cdm-core.jar

==== central: tried

  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/cdm-core-5.4.2.pom

  -- artifact edu.ucar#cdm-core;5.4.2!cdm-core.jar:

  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/cdm-core-5.4.2.jar

==== spark-packages: tried

  https://repos.spark-packages.org/edu/ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/cdm-core-5.4.2.pom

  -- artifact edu.ucar#cdm-core;5.4.2!cdm-core.jar:

  https://repos.spark-packages.org/edu/ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2/cdm-core-5.4.2.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: edu.ucar#cdm-core;5.4.2: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import StorageLevel
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

from sedona.spark import *
from sedona.core.geom.envelope import Envelope

config = SedonaContext.builder() .\
    config('spark.jars.packages',
           'org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-shaded-3.4_2.12:1.5.1,'
           'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.5.1-28.2'). \
    getOrCreate()

sedona = SedonaContext.create(config)
sc = sedona.sparkContext

print("Sedona context is " + sc)
```

I followed the official documentation, but it seems that there is an unresolved dependency issue, possibly related to missing packages or configurations. The official documentation does not provide an exhaustive list of the required dependencies for successful setup. Can you help clarify what additional configurations or packages might be needed to resolve this issue and set up Apache Sedona with PySpark 3.5.0 successfully?

Answer (score 4):

Due to a bug in Sedona 1.5.1, the cdm-core jar becomes a required dependency.

You can easily fix this by using this jar `org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-3.4_2.12:1.5.1`  . Note that we are not using the `shaded` jar.

`unshaded` jar is only supposed to be used by a Maven Resolver (e.g., spark.jar.packages is a maven resolver) because it has lots of compile dependencies to be downloaded by the resolver automatically. Those dependencies are not packaged in the sedona `unshaded` jar.

`shaded` jar is only supposed to be used when you don't have a resolver (e.g., in an environment that has no internet access)

Comment: Is this mentioned anywhere in the documentation? I've used shaded before and it worked, but now we don't use that? This seems like a massive change and I can't find it anywhere else but here, and the docs still list shaded as a jar. 

Docs: https://sedona.apache.org/1.5.1/tutorial/sql/

Code:

`config = SedonaContext.builder().config('spark.jars.packages', org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-shaded-3.0_2.12:1.5.1,' 'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.5.1-28.2').getOrCreate()`

Comment: @AlexSmith This bug is listed here: https://sedona.apache.org/1.5.1/setup/maven-coordinates/#use-sedona-shaded-fat-jars  However, when use `spark.jars.packages`, we recommend use the `unshaded` jar because `spark.jars.packages` has a maven resolver so there is no need to use a shaded jar.

Comment: Since Sedona 1.5.0, we start to release this unshaded jar for all Sedona logics. https://sedona.apache.org/1.5.1/setup/install-python/#prepare-sedona-spark-jar

Comment: Where can I manually download the 1.5.1 `unshaded` jars? Most of the links point to a `shaded` jar for download. I downloaded the .tgz binary for 1.5.1 and, except for the Snowflake jar, they are all `shaded`. Is the only other fix to go back to 1.5.0? Is there an estimated data for a fixed release?

Comment: @TheSteve0 Can you explain why you want to manually download a `unshaded` jar? `Unshaded` jar is only supposed to be downloaded by a Maven Resolver (e.g., spark.jar.packages is a maven resolver) because it has lots of compile dependencies to be downloaded by the resolver automatically. `shaded` jar is supposed to be used when you don't have a resolver (e.g., in an environment that has no internet access). But, anyways, you can always download the `unshaded` jar from Maven Central: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.sedona/sedona-spark-3.5_2.12

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the repository from which the jar files can be downloaded.  Here the repositories config is used to specify maven rep

The cdm-core can be found below

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.ucar/cdm-core/5.4.2

```
from sedona.spark import *

packages = "org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-shaded-3.4_2.12:1.5.1," \
           "org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.5.1-28.2," \
           "edu.ucar:cdm-core:5.4.2,"

repository = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"


config = SedonaContext.builder()\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", packages) \
    .config("spark.jars.repositories", repository) \
    .getOrCreate()

sedona = SedonaContext.create(config)
sc = sedona.sparkContext

print("Sedona context is ", sc)
```